# Get the exactly width and height of a component in Vaadin

Tags: html, css, vaadin

In vaadin, if I set width and height to undefined, I will get -1 when using getHeight()/getWidth() function.
if I use sizeful(), I will get 100%. But how can I get the exactly width and height of a component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Vaadin, the layout is realized by the client side engine in the browser and the concrete sizes of layout components usually depend on the size of the browser window. Component sizes are not sent back to the server by the Vaadin standard components.

Since all of your code is executed on the server, it cannot get at those values, either. You would need to program a special wrapper component that sends its size back to the server each time it changes.

---

**Update 2013-03-21:** I have developed the [SizeReporter add-on for Vaadin 7](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/sizereporter) which sends back the size of the component to the server and notifies you when the size changes.

Comment: Thanks for the SizeReporter add-on. However your link is currently broken.

Comment: This is what I get when I click the link: http://ft.trillian.im/cc29137816c530e2a68b328852a0d40c446b2a82/6l3JZhCKCSmvRe80vzaP0SnMGHYU5.jpg

Comment: Must be a problem on your side, the link is to https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/sizereporter%3avaadin

Comment: @IngoKegel In vaadin 8.6.2 it sends components width bigger or equal than 920px. smaller width are not sent back. is it a bug or normal behavior? thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not developing this add-on right now. If you find a solution, please feel free to submit a PR,

Comment: @IngoKegel it works actually as expected. i found the real problem. when a HorizontalLayout ist placed on the top, the ResizeReporter doesnt send smaller widths than horizonalLayout width.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it by call javascript function an get callback result.
Read more in http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#foundation/javascript-callback

somthing like this:

If you have HorizontalLayout h

```
HorizontalLayout h = new HorizontalLayout()
//...
h.setId("myId");
JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("myGetWidth",
   new JavaScriptFunction() {
       @Override
       public void call(final JSONArray arguments)
               throws JSONException {
         int width = arguments.getInt(0);
         //now you can do something with this width
       }
   });
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("myGetWidth(document.getElementById('" +h.getId() + "').clientWidth);");
```

Comment: Good hack to go with!

Comment: Thanx! That is exactly what is needed

Comment: how to pass the width to server side??

Comment: This did it for me, thanks. The SizeReporter thing above didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately not working in Vaadin 14. JavaScript has no .getCurrent() method.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's too late, but I post this here just to know:

Now, you could use this Add-On from the vaadin directory to accomplish that (https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/css-tools).

This Add-On simply allows you, given a certain component, to geather CSS info about it.
I'll put the code example here (that is the same you find in the Add-On page)

```
    RenderInfo.get(component, new Callback() {
            public void infoReceived(RenderInfo info) {
                   // Use the info
                   // All the properties are returned as Strings, e.g. "123px"
                   String width = info.getProperty(CssProperty.width);
            }
    },CssProperty.height, CssProperty.width);
```

In this way you get just Height and Width of the selected component!

Comment: Sorry, I have a problem when using the Add-On. I get the following exception `HTTP Status 500 - com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.vaadin.ui.Component.getApplication()Lcom/vaadin/Application;` Complaining about **RenderInfo.get** `at org.vaadin.csstools.RenderInfo.get(RenderInfo.java:45)`. Could you please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using Vaadin 6 or 7?

Comment: I am using Vaadin 7, I saw just now from the Vaadin directory that this extension is not available for Vaadin 7, is it right?

Comment: Yes... This extension is only available for vaadin 6!

Comment: It would be useful even for Vaadin 7.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that extension, thanks, but I would need to get the width of a `VerticalLayout` with `.setSizeFull()` in pixels and the VerticalLayout is not resizable, so that extension doesn't work for me as it only works with a resizable component and gives you the width of it only if you add a resize listener, which is not my case