# Show tooltip on text overflow in grid-cell

Tags: tooltip, overflow, vaadin, vaadin7, truncated

Using Vaadin 7 , I am trying to display "tooltip" (only) if the text in a grid cell is truncated  (with ellipsis  "...") ?

How can I find out if the text in the cell is truncated ?

I tried to find out the width of the column( comparing it to the length of the string in a cell). But the width of the column always returns "-1.0".

Thanks

Comment: What does `getMinimumWidth()` / `getMaximumWidth()` return?

Comment: getMaximumWidth()  also returns "-1.0" .

getMinimumWidth()   returns "10.0"

Comment: This topic will help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787649/get-the-exactly-width-and-height-of-a-component-in-vaadin